# Is this stylized version of the world turtle part of any known lore?

Tags: runes

We found this stylized world turtle flag and are wondering if it is anything "real" or just a modern artist version of the world turtle. Any ideas?

[image: Flag with turtle motif]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a modern reinterpretation of the [Lo Shu Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_Shu_Square) using symbols from western alchemy. The Lo Shu Square is a magic 3x3 square of numbers which according to a Chinese legend appeared on the back of a turtle. See this picture for comparison with the one you posted:

[image]

According to the "Earlier Heaven" Taoist [Bagua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua), one can associate the numbers 1,3,7 and 9 appearing on the turtle's back to the elements Earth, Fire, Water and Sky. In the flag you posted the triangles are [Alchemical Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alchemical_symbol) for the same elements (with the correspondence Sky=Air), although not in the same order. I have no clue regarding the middle symbol, though. One guess, but this is just speculation, is that it could be a stylized [Yellow Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_Dragon), associated with the center of the cosmos, and quintessence (the fifth element).

Answer (score 6):

To add on the answer by @Gullintani.

The middle sigil is Odins enchanted spear Gungnir.

[image]
<sub>[From the 18th century Icelandic manuscript NKS 1867 4to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_Royal_Library,_MS_NKS_1867_4%C2%B0)</sub>